# "Notice: Undefined index" on some values when pushing to array

Tags: php, arrays

I am adding some values with keys to an array:

```
public function addData($key, $value){
    $this->data[$key] =  $value;
}

//this is line y in another class
$dataHolder->addData($FieldNames[$i], $row{$FieldNames[$i]});
```

It works most of the time. But sometimes I get

```
Notice: Undefined index [keyvalue] in x.php in line y
```

The array is empty and the values and keys are from a database table.

Most of the fields is inserted without any problem, but some gives this error?
Any Ideas on why it works sometimes?

Comment: I'm guessing line y isn't the line you've shown us. Setting a value in an array should never produce an undefined index error like that, it will either create the key or overwrite an existing key. What is line y?

Comment: Probably there is no value in $key sometimes.

Comment: I am not sure why Notice is coming. It should not come because you are just setting the value, not retrieving it. Are you sure you are checking correct line number.

Comment: @veelen even if there is no value in key, it should still add a new row to the end of the array - [see this](https://eval.in/124280) for an example.

Comment: @Styphon You are totally right, I was too fast. Sorry.

Comment: @Styphon I added line y

Comment: OK, so where does `$i` come from? Perhaps you could post a bit more code so we can see where `$i` comes from and exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: It was from a for loop. I found the error and posted an answer. But thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem.
It was a stupid human error.

I forgot that the tablename I was using was hardcoded to a specific table. So it worked if the table I *thought* I was using and the table I was *actually* using, had field names in common...

The solution here is to take a break sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Delcare `$this->data = array();` above function

OR

It might be happen when `key` or `value` passing as empty value to function from database.

Comment: I have allready declered the array that way.
The key or the value is never empty. The db does not allow null on the fields.

Answer (score -1):

According to me, if you want to push elements in a variable, you must define that variable is an array. You must be using any looping to pushing values in array. for ex:

```
public function addData($key,$value)
{
   $array = array();
   for($i=a,$j=0;$j<26;$j++)
   {
    $array[$i]=$array[$j];
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need a loop to push values to an array?

Comment: The code I have works fine for most tables in the db, but on some tables some fields gives the notice

Comment: i just assumed for an example :/